# for loop wrong, or equation wrong. what do I need to write after my if statement?

Tags: java

I have just started learning java in netbeans at university. I have written a code to multiply the numbers between 4 and 30 by 3, so that my code will only print out the numbers >= to 4 and will not exceed 30 when multiplied by 3.

I would like my code to print out `there are 7 integers greater or equal....etc` but my code prints out  `there are 11 integers` I always get confused as to what I need to write after my for or while loops, I am pretty sure my maths is right but why is it calculating to 11 instead of 7?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start = 4, stop = 30, multiple = 3;

    countMultiples(start,stop, multiple);

}
public static void countMultiples(int start, int stop, int multiple){
    int numbers = 0;

    for(int i = start; i <=stop; i++)
        if(numbers * multiple <= stop)
            numbers++;


    System.out.println("there are " + numbers + " integers  greater or equal " + start + " and not exceeding " + stop);
    System.out.println("which multiplied by " + multiple);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo - change `if(numbers * multiple <= stop)` to `if(i * multiple <= stop)`

Comment: i guess you want `i* multiple <= stop`, as your using `numbers` to multiply currently, but that´s your count variable (how many occurences you already had).

Comment: `if(numbers * multiple <= stop)` <- Numbers is your counter for how many numbers you found that fit the criteria. It should'nt be part of this calculation and you probably meant to use your loop index `i` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have logic mistake at if condition inside for loop you just need to multiply `i * multiple`in order to get the expected result:

```
for(int i = start; i <=stop; i++){
        if(i * multiple <= stop){
            numbers++;
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void countMultiples(int start, int stop, int multiple){
    int numbers = 0;

    for(int i = start; i <=stop; i++) {
        if (i * multiple <= stop) { // <-- the numbers should be i
            numbers++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing inside the if is

- first you are multiplying with the number which starts from 0 and upon multiplication the overall result is <=30 and your if condition satisfies and it increment your count.

*The difference that you are getting in your count is because you are starting from 0 ,but as you mentioned your number should begin from 4.

So instead of

```
 if(numbers * multiple <= stop)
        numbers++;
```

do this

```
if(i*multiple <=stop)
    numbers++;
```

Since now you start from i which has its initial value as 4, you shoukd get the right count

Answer (score 0):

You missed the logic here `if(numbers * multiple <= stop)`
Do it like this

```
 for(int i = start; i <=stop; i++)
     if(i * multiple <= stop)
         numbers++;
```

Answer (score 0):

okay first thing first, 4 and 30 are not included right ?
so when setting the `i` add 1 to it.
then in the condition of the loop remove the equal sign , so it will stop before reaching the number 30.

```
for(int i = start+1 ; i <stop; i++){//start checking from number 5 , remove the equal sign

    if(multiple* i  < stop){ //also remove the equal sign here
     numbers++;
         System.out.println(multiple* i+" :there are " + numbers + " integers  greater or equal " + start + " and not exceeding " + stop);

     }
```